# libGDX - Texture Mapping issues

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx

I am currently in the process of creating a small, 3D game in libGDX. Unfortunately, I am having some issues with texturing. This is a very simple game, so I am using boxes with pictures on them for the monsters.

From what I can tell the createBox method in ModelBuilder takes the texture you pass in and slaps it on the front of the box, then rotates it 90 degrees and slaps it on the right side, and so on. I would like for the box to look the same no matter which side you are viewing it from (top and bottom don't matter). Is there a way I can modify the current box to change how it deals with textures, or is there another solution?

Example Code:

```
// Adds new box to list of models using createBox method of ModelBuilder
models.add(modelBuilder.createBox(3f, 3f, 6f, minM, Usage.Position | Usage.Normal | Usage.TextureCoordinates));

// Increments count to keep track of model
count++;

// Adds instance of model to list of instances to be rendered later using ModelBatch
instances.add(new ModelInstance(models.get(count), (m.getEnd().getX() * spacing), (m.getEnd().getY() * spacing), z));
```

Problem:

When rendered the front of the box looks like this:

[image]

but the right side, it looks like this:

[image]

I want every side to look like the front.

Thanks for the replies so far!

Comment: You may get better answers if you provide minimal example code for users to work from.  Not only are you more likely to get answers, the answers may include modified code rather than just "you need to do X".

Comment: There is not an automated way to do that. You could look at the source for the `createBox` method and copy it, modifying the UVs. Or you could just model a box the way you like in a modeling program and import it.